# Permissions to allow files to be written, but not read, overwritten or modified

Tags: permissions, acl, freebsd, samba, cifs

I'm setting up a file share for a small group (CIFS/samba on FreeNAS, so the base system is FreeBSD/ZFS using ACLs).

I want to allow users to put stuff into a folder on the share - but not to be able to read the share's contents once written. Since they can't read the shares contents or get directory listings, the share will be "flat" (no subdirectories) and they mustn't be able to overwrite or alter files that already exist unseen there, since they couldn't see them to avoid the overwrite and because it allows probing of filenames that exist or don't.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, HTTP upload page + some logic on the server would be probably best in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entierly sure, but you should be able to do it as described below.

> Grant Write permission for the Users group that is applied to This Folder only. (This is an option available on the Advanced page.)
>
> If each user needs to have certain permissions to the files that he or she dropped, you can create a permission entry for the Creator Owner well-known security identifier (SID) and apply it to Subfolder and files only.
> For example, you can grant the Read and Write permission to the Creator Owner SID on the drop folder and apply it to all subfolders and files. This grants the user who dropped or created the file (the Creator Owner) the ability to read and write to the file. The Creator Owner can then access the file through the Run command by using \ServerName\DropFolder\FileName.
>
> Grant Full Control permission to the group manager.

Quote from Microsoft TechNet: [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the files inaccessible, then why don't you use cron to move the files that have been written away from this share to some other.

This would be kind of like a spool directory in this case. There are still two problems:

1) Larger files could be moved away while the user still writes them.
2) You need to handle the case where the user saves a file that collides with the one in the destination directory.

These cases are dangerous, because you can lose data.

Alternatively, it is also possible that rsync has got all the tools to solve the problem, because there is an option that makes backups and one option that makes sure that you never delete files.